# Would veganism become much more popular in society mostly made up of shapeshifters?

Tags: science-in-society, shapeshifters

In my story the western world and other wealthy countries have access to shape shifting technology. How it works is that tiny microscopic nanobots flow through the bloodstream and can kinda turn a switch in the human body from animal back to human. This is why the biggest size limit would be something along the lines of a flea, because anything smaller the nanobots would be too large to flow through the bloodstream. And of course any animal that doesn't have blood you can't turn into. The animal the person receives is completely random because the intended use of the technology is to preserve animal species even if the entire real species goes extinct. So in theory most animals can't go extinct completely because they can always extract sperm and eggs from some people who turn into it and thus save the species.
When you turn into the animal you can feel its instincts/thoughts, for ex: You turn into a rabbit and you're being hunted, your rabbit mind will tell you to run and will panic. But overtime and the more you morph the more you feel and notice its instincts.

Comment: This seems like something that is entirely up to your discretion as worldbuilder. We could talk about what we each individually think would happen but that's just us sharing opinions. Open ended discussions like that are not a good fit for this site.

Comment: @sphennings for individual characters surely, but as a question about general societal trends based off of real world psychology & sociology? perhaps not entirely so? In a world were there's a danger that little bunny you found in your garden might be your son or daughter it may not be unreasonable to posit a general trend toward a 'better safe than sorry' approach to hunting & meat eating / doubtful anything but answers in the most general terms can reasonably be defended as anything but personal opinion though.

Comment: @Pelinore That's a very interesting opinion you have. Seems like a worldbuilder could draw conclusions similar to yours should they wish. Seems like they could conclude otherwise with relatively little effort.

Comment: It seems to me that you could end-up with a polarised possibility - many staunchly vegan, many keen on the flesh alternative - and a feud between them. Lends itself to a bit of drama in the setting anyhow, which would be a great advantage of this solution.

Comment: @sphennings the problem I see with the question is that it's self evidently yes, they already exist with numerous reasons for their choice (that I personally consider frivolous) so add an extra more legitimate reason to avoid meat to the reasons they already have & it would be unreasonable to consider there'd not be more of them as a result, but how many more can only be opinion so it was pointless asking.

Comment: If you can shapeshift into animals, there's a variety of ways to make ethical meat with such technology, so it's likely to lead to more meat eating.

Comment: @Pelinore or it goes into ritual canibalism...

Comment: @Trish ritual? dunno about that, but a love bacon, anyone 'choosing' to become a pig? we could call that suicide I suppose, a barbecue is 'sort of' a ritual gathering (the way some people do it), so ritual suicide?

Answer (score 5):

**Yes, of course**

Being introduced to several different viewpoints by this kind of immersion allows the shapeshifter to emphasize more. There is a quote in some Pratchett nevel, *you may not eat it if it had a name*. Being it would be even more powerful.

**No, of course not**

People would be exposed to the minds of carnivores. A cat patiently stalking a mouse. A pack of wolves chasing deer. A hawk soaring above the fields. Would those be the *better experiences* out of the various options? Say you've been a rabbit, a frog, and a lion. Which one would you *like* to reminisce about more? Which one do you tell to other people?

Answer (score 2):

## No, as with technology that advanced you could grow meat.

If you have the ability to shapeshift into animals, you can also shapeshift insects into bigger animals and eat them, or do a variety of other things. You'd probably also get computers with organic shells shapeshifting into animals so people could hunt animals, along with people using mind backups so people could hunt them and eat them and not die.

Ethical meat eating would be cheaper and more common.